# haskell facebook example

Tags: facebook, haskell

I am stuck with haskell types.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main (
    main
) where

import qualified Facebook as FB
import Network.HTTP.Conduit (withManager)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import System.IO

app :: FB.Credentials
app = FB.Credentials "localhost" "249348058430770" "..."

url :: FB.RedirectUrl
url = "http://localhost/fb"

perms :: [FB.Permission]
perms = ["user_about_me", "email"]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    fbAuthUrl <- FB.getUserAccessTokenStep1 url perms
    liftIO $ print fbAuthUrl
    argument <- readLn
    token <- FB.getUserAccessTokenStep2 url [argument]
    withManager $ \manager -> do
        FB.runFacebookT app manager $ do
            u <- FB.getUser "me" [] token
            liftIO $ print (FB.userEmail u)
```

error

```
src/Main.hs:23:18:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO t0'
                with actual type `FB.FacebookT
                                    FB.Auth m0 text-0.11.2.0:Data.Text.Internal.Text'
    In the return type of a call of `FB.getUserAccessTokenStep1'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      fbAuthUrl <- FB.getUserAccessTokenStep1 url perms
    In the expression:
      do { fbAuthUrl <- FB.getUserAccessTokenStep1 url perms;
           liftIO $ print fbAuthUrl;
           argument <- readLn;
           token <- FB.getUserAccessTokenStep2 url [argument];
           .... }
```

package http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fb

Comment: The type `main :: liftIO` doesn't make any sense. Do you mean `main :: IO ()`?

Comment: I don't know ? I don't return any IO () like putStrLn ?

Comment: Help us to help you: 1. When asking for help with an error, always include the full error message in your question. 2. When asking about a package that didn't come bundled with your compiler, always tell us the package name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me preface this answer by the disclaimer that I've never actually used the Facebook API or the `Conduits` library, so I'm not sure if this code actually does anything sensible, but by going with just the type information, I think this is what you were trying to do

```
main :: IO ()
main = withManager $ \manager -> FB.runFacebookT app manager $ do
    fbAuthUrl <- FB.getUserAccessTokenStep1 url perms
    liftIO $ print fbAuthUrl
    argument <- liftIO $ readLn
    token <- FB.getUserAccessTokenStep2 url [argument]
    u <- FB.getUser "me" [] (Just token)
    liftIO $ print (FB.userEmail u)
```

The main pitfall is that `main` in Haskell must *always* have the type `IO a`, but you are trying to use a value of type `FacebookT Auth m ()` as your `main`. Your implementation is on the right track, but the `runFacebookT` and `withManager` need to be the first thing in the function.

Type-wise, the actual do-block has the type `FacebookT Auth (ResourceT IO) ()`. The `runFacebookT` function is used to unwrap the `FacebookT` transformer, resulting in a `ResourceT IO ()` value, which is in turn processed by `withManager` to produce a plain old `IO ()`.

One additional problem was that you originally had a `readLn` in your do-block without `liftIO`, which was confusing the type-inference. I also added the missing `Just` to the `FB.getUser` call.

Comment: `main` in Haskell can actually be `IO a`.

Comment: print works perfect but i get `user error (Prelude.readIO: no parse)` when doing readLn?

Comment: What are you trying to input? `readLn` is expecting to get something like `("foo", "bar")`

Comment: the response code from facebook after accepting the app permission? `http://localhost/fb?code=AQBsA9rMt6...aXvBbXIuR8#_=_`