# haskell model export error

Tags: haskell

Reference [haskell facebook example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596234/haskell-facebook-example) works perfect, but now I can't figure out how to split it in a separate module so I can do something useful with it. Also I can't figure out what type I need to put for fbEmail fbUrl and if I need to put OverloadedStrings in every module? Maybe my thinking process is wrong and its simple not possible to separate the import Network.HTTP.Conduit (withManager) from main?

login.hs

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
module Login (
    fbUrl,
    fbEmail
) where

import qualified Facebook as FB
import Network.HTTP.Conduit (withManager)
import Data.Text
import Data.ByteString.Internal (ByteString)

app :: FB.Credentials
app = FB.Credentials "localhost" "249348058430770" "..."

url :: FB.RedirectUrl
url = "http://localhost/fb"

perms :: [FB.Permission]
perms = ["user_about_me", "email"]

fbUrl = FB.getUserAccessTokenStep1 url perms

fbEmail c = withManager $ \manager -> FB.runFacebookT app manager $ do
    t <- FB.getUserAccessTokenStep2 url [c]
    u <- FB.getUser "me" [] (Just t)
    return $ FB.userEmail u
```

main.hs

```
module Main (
  main
) where

import Login
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
    u <- fbUrl
    print u
    a <- readLn
    e <- fbEmail a
    print e
```

I get the following error

```
src/Main.hs:11:10:
Couldn't match expected type `IO t0'
            with actual type `fb-0.9.6:Facebook.Monad.FacebookT
                                fb-0.9.6:Facebook.Monad.Auth m0 Data.Text.Internal.Text'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: u <- fbUrl
In the expression:
  do { u <- fbUrl;
       print u;
       a <- readLn;
       e <- fbEmail a;
       .... }
In an equation for `main':
    main
      = do { u <- fbUrl;
             print u;
             a <- readLn;
             .... }
```

CODE UPDATE 6: see answer

Comment: You need the overloaded strings extension only in those files where you want to treat syntactic strings (things enclosed in `"`) as non-`String` types (such as `Text`).

Comment: ok so I can drop OverloadedStrings in main? return seem to to fix `FB.userEmail u` but now i get the following see update.

Comment: `fbUrl :: Monad m => FB.FacebookT FB.Auth m (Maybe Text)` Not in scope: type constructor or class Text

Comment: now i get this, see update 3 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise what was going on in the comments the issue was, essentially, threefold. You tried to return a `Maybe Text` rather than a `FacebookT ... (Maybe Text)`, due to missing a `return`, the lack of type signatures made the monomorphism restriction kick inm and finally you forgot to `runFacebookT` in `main`.

EDIT: The fourth problem is that you're giving `fbEmail` a too polymorphic type, the type checker complains that the type variable `a` actually has to be *exactly* `(ByteString, ByteString)`. EDIT: Using a type *variable* here states that the function could be applied to *anything*, which isn't the case, as `getUserAccessTokenStep2` wants a list of pairs of `ByteStrings` (rather than just an arbitrary list).

EDIT: The fifth issue is due to the requirement that `FacebookT` be taken over *any* monad is too weak (withManager requires it to be a bunch of more specific things, such as `MonadIO`). As you can see in the error it's rather a long list of things, and you might be better off just removing the type signature from `fbEmail` and enable the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` extension (just add it to the list of extensions where you have `OverloadedStrings`.

Note that generally you should have explicit type declarations, but I'm not too familiar with the conduits package (I'm more of a pipes person :P), and I don't know if there is some constraint synonym trick there to make it less verbose.

Unless these were just silly typos you might want to read up on monads and monad transformers in one of the many tutorials floating around (or check the [haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad)).

Also questions such as these might be considered a little too specific for stackoverflow (see the FAQ) and more appropriate to the haskell IRC channel (I'll flag it once we've managed to got it running the way you want, but in future I suggest you try the IRC channel on FreeNode :)).

Comment: i am still add 'hello world' so its a accomplishment to get me this far :) Sorry I don't know how to fix the (ByteString, ByteString) either.

Comment: Change the type variable `a` in the type signature `fbEmail` to `(ByteString, ByteString)` and add an import `import Data.ByteString.Internal (ByteString)` (you might also get away with `(FB.ByteString, FB.ByteString)`, I'm not sure whether or not the facebook package re-exports).

Comment: need update 4 sorry error to big for comments

Comment: update 5 with `NoMonomorphismRestriction` gave me the same error?

Comment: @GertCuykens You didn't remove the type signature of `fbEmail`

Comment: @GertCuykens `fbUrl` is also a `FacebookT ...` value, and needs to be run with some form of `runFacebookT` (as before). Also, you might want to reserve to use of "great comments" to actually great comments (an upvote on the answer is quite enough if you think the answer is helpful). Sorry if I have a lecturing tone :)

Comment: So its not possible to separate FB from main module?

Comment: @GertCuykens I'm not quite sure what you mean, run `fbUrl` the way you run `fbEmail` (with a withManager e.t.c.).

Comment: a wait i think i got to at `return $` for fbUrl too?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14258/discussion-between-tilo-wiklund-and-gert-cuykens)